# Which is the best and fastest way to compare two urls?

Tags: php, mysql, compare

I have two tables with list of urls fetched from different sources.

I want to find the common entries and put them in separate table.

This is what I'm doing:

1. find md5 hash of url while fetching them.
2. Store them in a column.
3. I fetch one table as an array, run a loop through it and insert the values from other table where md5 hash is the same.

EDIT: Should I strip the urls of "http://' and 'www.'

I want to know any other method, which is better and faster, using which I can perform the above.

I am using PHP + MySQL

Comment: I'm kind of curious -- can anyone tell me why you would hash the URL at all?  Is it to get an easier-to-compare data type (instead of string searches)?

Comment: Just a bit of warning: MD5 will have clashes if the number of URLs are significant - resulting in false positives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MD5 is a little bit slow if you need real speed. Try [MurmurHash](http://sites.google.com/site/murmurhash/)

You should do the following transformations before hash calculation:

- Strip "http://" and www.
- Strip trailing slash
- Normalize URL ([urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode) it)

Comment: BTW, not sure PHP implementation of MurmurHash will be faster than md5 function. That needs testing. Anyway for REAL speed, you can make PHP plugin.

Comment: I guess implementing MumurHash in PHP will be tough. Are there any other faster hashing methods?

Comment: You can use mhash extension, but I doubt you will get any speed improvement: http://develobert.blogspot.com/2007/09/php5-hash-benchmarks.html

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
INSERT INTO table3  (SELECT url FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.hash = table2.hash)
```

That's not a valid SQL-statement, but a nested query like that should read urls from table1 and table2 that match by their hash and put them in table3.

EDIT:
If you want to sanitize your input urls (e.g. removing GET-variables), I'd do that before saving them to tabel1 and table2. I wouldn't remove http and www as "https://somesite" and "http://somesite" as well as "www.somesite.com" and "somesite.com" may have different content.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE hash IN (SELECT hash FROM table2)
```

You may probably also want to have a look at the concept of table joins.